# How do I stop accepting a string at Enter in C++

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I'm trying to make a program to find the most common characters in a Hangman game. I want the user to enter a list of movie names(separated by Enter) in standard input. The movie names will be of variable length.

However, the program does not stop accepting input till all the characters of the MOVIE_NAME_SIZE are entered. I tried checking for '\0' and '\n'. It doesn't seem to work. What am I doing incorrectly? Also, is there an easier method to do this?

P.S. - I'm sorry if this is question has been asked before. I looked, and it was suggested to use a method called getline(), but that was for the entire string, while I need to access individual characters.

```
char movieList[MAX_MOVIES][MAX_NAME_SIZE];
char CapitalAlphabetList[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
char smallAlphabetList[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
char numberList[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
int alphabetCount[26] = {0};
int numberCount[10] = {0};
int i, j, k;

for(i = 0; i < MAX_MOVIES; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < MAX_NAME_SIZE; j++)
    {
        cin >> movieList[i][j];

        if(movieList[i][j] == '\0')
            break;

        for(k = 0; k < 26; k++)
            if((movieList[i][j] == smallAlphabetList[k]) || (movieList[i][j] == CapitalAlphabetList[k]))
                alphabetCount[k]++;

        for(k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            if(movieList[i][j] == numberList[k])
                numberCount[k]++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check for `"STOP"` or `"NONE"` instead of catching whatever `cin` scrapes as the last character.  What about using `cin` on a temporary variable and then checking against `size == 0`?

Comment: @Matt I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate? `"STOP"` or `"NONE"` will not be entered by the user. Are they keywords?

Comment: They're something you would have to type to get it to stop.  If you want it to stop on no input instead I would catch the `cin` into a string and then check the length of the string.  This is more of a C question if your'e not using the `std::string` though.  The only thing that is C++ like is your call to `cin`

Comment: @Matt Thanks! I'll try that. However, shouldn't an alternate(easier) solution exist? Because the string could always contain more than one STOP or NONE unintentionally(part of the movie name), but only one Newline character will be present at all times.

Comment: I don't recall what `cin` reads as the last character, but just don't read user input directly into `movieList[][]`.  Use another variable to read the user input and then write branch statements off of this temporary variable.  I think it's a little weird to read user input directly into `movieList[][]` as well as checking `movieList[][]` for when to stop..

Comment: Also `cin` isn't a character wise operation.  You're calling `cin` for every single character of `MAX_NAME_SIZE` which makes no sense.  You should be reading `cin` in the outer loop.

Comment: No `string`, no `vector`. Heck, not even C's `isalpha()` or `isdigit()` are in evidence. I get that twitch in the corner of my eye again looking at this... As for `getline()`, why not *read* the line and then *parse* it in memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a condition in your code like :

```
if(string_name.length()==0)
break;
```

this works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned not wanting to use `getline`, but you can still access individual characters of strings. For instance, if you declare

```
char exampleMovie[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
```

outside your outer loop, you can place the following code inside your outer loop to store a new [C-style string](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/) for each movie name:

```
cin.getline(exampleMovie, MAX_NAME_SIZE);
```

Then, in your inner loop (which would loop from 1 to `strlen(exampleMovie)` - which would save you operations for short-named movies), you could access each character of `exampleMovie` with the following code:

```
if (exampleMovie[j] == smallAlphabetList[k]) // etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In short, this is how you can stop at an empty `ENTER` key press in a loop using `strcmp()` and `cin.getline()` in your program. with these lines. This works since `cin` adds a `'\0'` when enter is pressed.

§Formatted input from a `std::istream` into a character array will null-terminate the input, as specified in C++11 27.7.2.2.3/9:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    char name[256]={' '};
    while( true ){
      memset(name,'\0',sizeof(name)); // reset char array
      cout << ">";
      cin.getline (name,256); // cin addes a \0 when empty enter is pressed.
      cout<<"\n"<<name<<"\n";
      if ( strcmp( name, "\0" ) == 0 )  break; // break at empty enter key
    }


  cout << " \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get()
  return 0;
}
```

The program had to be altered, now a `while()` loop handles input until a empty enter key is pressed. 
Then after that it functions as you intended it to.

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    const int MAX_MOVIES = 100;
    const int MAX_NAME_SIZE = 100;

    char movieList[MAX_MOVIES][MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    char CapitalAlphabetList[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char smallAlphabetList[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char numberList[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    int alphabetCount[26] = {0};
    int numberCount[10] = {0};
    int i=0, j=0, k=0 , l=0;

    memset(movieList,'\0',sizeof(movieList));
    cout<<"Movie Title Hangman \n\n";

    while( true ){
        for(l=0;l<i;l++)cout<<movieList[l]<<"\n";

        cout<<"Turn number "<<i<<" , enter movie >";
        memset(movieList[i],'\0',MAX_NAME_SIZE);
        cin.getline (movieList[i],256);

        cout<<"------------------------------------------\n";

        if( strcmp(movieList[i],"\0") ==0){

            for (i=0;i<MAX_MOVIES ;i++){
                for(j=0;j<MAX_NAME_SIZE ;j++){

                    for(k = 0; k < 26; k++){ 
                       if((movieList[i][j] == smallAlphabetList[k]) || (movieList[i][j] == CapitalAlphabetList[k]))
                        alphabetCount[k]++;
                    }

                    for(k = 0; k < 10; k++){ 
                            if(movieList[i][j] == numberList[k])
                                numberCount[k]++;
                    }

                }
            }
         break; 

        }
       i++;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"The most common characters are: \n\n";
    for(k = 0; k < 26; k++) cout<<""<<smallAlphabetList[k] <<" = "<< alphabetCount[k]<<"\t";

    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(k = 0; k < 10; k++) cout<<""<<numberList[k] <<" = "<<  numberCount[k]<<"\t";


  cout << " \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get()
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read into a string, then look at the characters in that string.

A `map` is much simpler for counting occurrences in

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::map<char, int> letterCounts;
std::map<char, int> numberCounts;

for (std::string movie; std::getline(cin, movie); )
{
    for (char c : movie)
    {
        if (std::isalpha(c)) 
        {
            ++letterCounts[std::tolower(c)];
        }
        if (std::isdigit(c))
        {
            ++numberCounts[c];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you don't need the `map` to be sorted, will be better to use `unordered_map` in this case